# Implementar DataTables.net

Tags: jquery, html, html5, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Me encuentro implementando DataTables.net pero no me esta haciendo la paginación, estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC 5, el código que manejo es el siguiente.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Proveedor";
}

<h2>Proveedor</h2>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>

<link href="~/Content/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <table id="proveedores" class="table table-hover display" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <td>ProveedorId</td>
            <td>Razón Social</td>
            <td>Número documento</td>
            <td>Dirección</td>
            <td>Teléfono</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>ProveedorId</td>
            <td>Razón Social</td>
            <td>Número documento</td>
            <td>Dirección</td>
            <td>Teléfono</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var row in ViewBag.ListarProveedor)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@row.ProveedorId</td>
                <td>@row.RazonSocial</td>
                <td>@row.NumeroDocumento</td>
                <td>@row.Direccion</td>
                <td>@row.Telefono</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>  
</table>


<script src="~/scripts/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#proveedores").DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Documentación
[DataTables.net](https://datatables.net/manual/installation)

Video Tutorial
[Datatables Plugin Instalación y Configuración](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sS0QtJato6I)

Layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Errores]

Comment: Cambia la referencia del datatables al `_Layout`

Comment: @JuankGlezz Si, pegue una imagen lo cambie el js pero no funciona

Comment: @PedroÁvila no esta haciendo la paginacion por que tienes dos `<td>`, p.e. `<td>Teléfono</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>` de sobra, un tabla tiene que ser bien estructurada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que [comenta x-rw](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49482/implementar-datatables-net/49487#comment86889_49482) también es valido y seguiría sin hacer la paginación.

Si lo que quieres es mostrar iconos en esos espacios vacíos haz lo siguiente:

```
<thead> 
  <tr> 
    <td>ProveedorId</td> 
    <td>Razón Social</td> 
    <td>Número documento</td> 
    <td>Dirección</td> 
    <td>Teléfono</td> 
    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td> 
    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td> 
  </tr> 
</thead>
```

y en tu `<tbody>` puedes hacer lo siguiente como [comento @Flxtr](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35436678#35436678):

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var row in ViewBag.ListarProveedor)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@row.ProveedorId</td>
            <td>@row.RazonSocial</td>
            <td>@row.NumeroDocumento</td>
            <td>@row.Direccion</td>
            <td>@row.Telefono</td>
            <td><a href="Controller/Action/@row.ProveedorId">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a></td> 
            <td><a href="Controller/Action/@row.ProveedorId">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a></td> 
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Ahora explico porque seguiría sin hacer paginación.

Lo que hace `RenderBody()` es renderizar la vista donde tienes tu tabla, te marca un error de que no encuentra la referencia de ensamblado de jQuery por que datatables esta declarado antes que jQuery, hay dos cosas que puedes hacer:

1.- Cambiar el encabezado del `_layout` de esta manera:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    <script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

2.- Cambiar los `scripts` de tu vista al `_Layout` o bien crear una sección de `scripts`:

en tu vista:

```
@section scripts {
  <script src="~/scripts/datatables.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#proveedores").DataTable();
    });
  </script>
}
```

en el `_Layout`

```
...
</div>
  <script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Comment: Siguiendo el paso 1, que sigue?

Comment: solo es de ejecutar la pagina sin problemas porque lo que te genera el error es que no se encuentra una referencia a la librería de jquery desde la librería de datatables, y este error es por las posiciones de declaración de estas

Comment: Entonces la forma de poner las referencias en el Layout es ponerlos en el Head?

Comment: <td><a href="Controller/Action/@row.ProveedorId"> estoy llamando a un action de mi controller y llamando a otra vista que yo desee y estoy tomando el valor del id, verdad

Comment: así es, es la forma mas fácil que se me ocurre, otra es abrir un modal y llenar la informacion después de hacer una peticion ajax por lo que es un poco más complicado a mi parecer